# Python2 - using min/max on None type

Tags: python-2.x, min, nonetype

I noticed that while the 'max' function do well on None type:

```
In [1]: max(None, 1)
Out[1]: 1
```

'min' function doesn't return anything:

```
In [2]: min(None, 1)
In [3]:
```

Maybe it's because there is no definition for min(None, 1)?
So why in max case, it return the number?
Is None treated like '-infinity'?

Comment: Note that this does not work in python3 where the relation between None and scalars is undefined. The code will raise a TypeError.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As jamylak wrote, `None` is simply not printed by Python shells.

This is convenient because *all functions return something*: when no value is specified, they return `None`:

```
>>> def f():
...     print "Hello"
...     
>>> f()
Hello
>>> print f()  # f() returns None!
Hello
None
```

This is why Python shells do not print a *returned* None value. `print None` is different, though, as it explicitly asks Python to print the `None` value.

---

As for comparisons, `None` is *not* considered to be -infinity.

The [general rule](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) for Python 2 is that objects that cannot be compared in any meaningful way don't raise an exception when compared, but instead return some arbitrary result. In the case of CPython, the arbitrary rule is the following:

> Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type
>   names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison
>   are ordered by their address.

Python 3 raises an exception, for non-meaningful comparisons like `1 > None` and the comparison done through `max(1, None)`.

---

If you do need -infinity, Python offers `float('-inf')`.

Comment: So, why max(None,1) return 1 ? it's arbitrary?

Comment: Note that this rule only applies to Python 2. In Python 3 it's fixed and you get a meaningful error message `unorderable types: int() < NoneType()`. @mclafee They both returned a value, if you read EOLs explanation it's very clear

Comment: @mclafee: `max(None, 1)` is undefined indeed. The "order by type name" rule for CPython 2 that I quoted does not seem to apply to the comparison between an integer and `None`, because  `None` is of type `'NoneType'`, which comes after `'int'`. Maybe the second rule does apply, though (in a test I did `id(1) > id(None)` was `True`).

Comment: @EOL: i'm not sure wat you testing in "id(1) > id(None)"? id return object id. I tried to test "type(1) > type(None)" which is False...

Comment: @mclafee: `id()` returns, in CPython, the address of an object, which is the way some objects are compared in CPython (http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id).

Answer (score 7):

It does return something, the python shell just doesn't print `None`

```
>>> min(None, 1)
>>> print min(None, 1)
None
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really want a value that is always going to compare less than any other, you need to create a little class:

```
class ValueLessThanAllOtherValues(object):
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return -1

# really only need one of these
ValueLessThanAllOtherValues.instance = ValueLessThanAllOtherValues()
```

This class will compare against values of any other type:

```
tiny = ValueLessThanAllOtherValues.instance
for v in (-100,100,0,"xyzzy",None):
    print(v)
    print(v > tiny)
    print(tiny < v)
    # use builtins
    print(min(tiny,v))
    print(max(tiny,v))
    # does order matter?
    print(min(v,tiny))
    print(max(v,tiny))
    print()
```

Prints:

```
-100
True
True
<__main__.ValueLessThanAllOtherValues object at 0x2247b10>
-100
<__main__.ValueLessThanAllOtherValues object at 0x2247b10>
-100

100
True
True
<__main__.ValueLessThanAllOtherValues object at 0x2247b10>
100
<__main__.ValueLessThanAllOtherValues object at 0x2247b10>
100

0
True
True
<__main__.ValueLessThanAllOtherValues object at 0x2247b10>
0
<__main__.ValueLessThanAllOtherValues object at 0x2247b10>
0

xyzzy
True
True
<__main__.ValueLessThanAllOtherValues object at 0x2247b10>
xyzzy
<__main__.ValueLessThanAllOtherValues object at 0x2247b10>
xyzzy

None
True
True
<__main__.ValueLessThanAllOtherValues object at 0x2247b10>
None
<__main__.ValueLessThanAllOtherValues object at 0x2247b10>
None
```

tiny is even less than itself!

```
print(tiny < tiny)
True
```

Comment: It is not exactly true that your `ValueLessThanAllOtherValues` is smaller than anything else. For instance, any other class defined in the same way yields objects that are smaller, when put on the left side of a comparison. The reason is that the `__cmp__()` of the *first* object in the comparison is called first (so your `__cmp__()` might not get called).

Comment: Great fleas have little fleas upon their backs to bite 'em,
    And little fleas have lesser fleas, and so ad infinitum.

Comment: You don't need to this in numpy, that's what [`np.NINF`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html) is for, at least for numerics.